# How to return a template array in c++

Tags: c++, arrays, templates

sortedArray – takes: an array, its size, boolean variable ascending, boolean variable inPlace.

It will then return the sorted array.

If ascending = false, the array will be sorted in descending order.

If inPlace = false, the original array will not be changed.

(To sort the array, I am using the function sort. And if needed, I am using the function reverseArray).

n is the size of array arr[].

```
template<class T>
T* sortedArray(T arr[], int n,bool asc,bool inplc) 
{ 
if(inplc)
    {
    sort(arr,arr+n);
    return arr;
    }
else if (inplc&&!asc)
    {
    sort(arr,arr+n);
    reverse(arr,arr+n);
    return arr;
    }
else if (!inplc&&asc)
    {
    T* arr1=new T[n];
    for(int i=0; i<n;i++)
        {
        arr1[i]=arr[i];
        }
    sort(arr1,arr1+n);
    return arr1;
    }
else 
    {
    T* arr1=new T[n];
    for(int i=0; i<n;i++)
        {
        arr1[i]=arr[i];
        }
    sort(arr1,arr1+n);
    reverse(arr1,arr1+n);
    return arr1;        
    }
}
```

The errors are fixed.

Comment: Why not simply using `std::array<T,n>`?

Comment: `T arr1[n];...return arr1` -- This will not work, as you're returning the address of a local variable.  Why do all of this stuff with pointers (which you're getting all wrong), and instead just use `std::array` and `std::sort`?